# Is there a technique for when a verb is used to conjure up a distinct image?

Tags: literary-techniques, literary-device

In *The Crucible*, Arthur Miller describes the love between John Proctor and Elizabeth Proctor as an "emotion flowing between them". In my interpretation, the verb
"flowing" connotes the movement of water, thereby equating the nouns of"emotion" and "water". Is there a technique that describes this except for just "imagery"?

Comment: Given that [***All language is metaphor***](https://www.quora.com/Is-metaphor-a-universal-linguistic-device-especially-in-non-Indo-European-languages), perhaps the short answer here is just ***language** [is the "technique" by which we make meaningful connections between different real-world entities and abstractions].*

Comment: Your question is based on the false premise that *the verb "flowing" connotes the movement of water*. Did you check the dictionary definition? [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flow) defines it as a "stream" (which, again, doesn't just mean water) and also mentions molasses, conversation, lines (contours), a gown, wealth and oil. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/flow) refers quite tautologically to "of a fluid, gas, or electricity".

Answer (score 1):

This is just metaphorical language; "flow" is here used on a greater level of abstraction than it is in "cash flow" for instance, but the literal meaning that is found in "water flow" is still what one refers to as one tries to come up with an
explanation on the basis of comparison; it makes of this usage a metaphorical one.

Comment: Emotions, being non-physical, can be described in all kinds of physical ways. Water is a pretty basic component of humans and their lives, so it's always available in their metaphors, too. And since emotions are mysterious, they can share all the mystery and mythology of water. Read _Even Cowgirls Get The Blues_ for more details about water, the ace of elements.